# Не конвертируется переменная из string в int

Tags: c#

У меня есть взятая из буфера обмена скопированная из браузера 194 и она не конвертируется, пишет

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.FormatException" в mscorlib.dll Дополнительные сведения: Входная строка имела неверный формат.

Что делать?

```
string CS = Clipboard.GetText();
int css = Convert.ToInt32(CS);
```

Comment: Как конвертируете? Код?

Comment: string CS = Clipboard.GetText();
 int css = Convert.ToInt32(CS);

Comment: Добавьте его в вопрос и воспользуйтесь функцией форматирования кода, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ваш код рабочий -- "194" без проблем конвертируется в число. Посмотрите в отладчике, что находится в переменной `CS`.

Comment: Проблема в том, что копируется в буфер обмена только 194, а заноситься в переменную CS "Кто поместил это в своё избранное? Поклонники этого товара:194", можно ли из этой строки взять только цифры?

Comment: @Александр Используй регулярку. Самое банальное, это \d+ , если других цифр в буфере быть не может.

Comment: @Александр: Тогда это _не_ число. У вас есть строка текста, и из неё нужно вытащить число. Это совсем разные задачи.

Comment: Покажите ваше число в юникодах, может у вас не *числа*, а символы **похожие** на числа из друго (верхнего) набора символов. 194 т.е. CS.ToCharArray() должно дать [49 '1',57 '9',52 '4'].

Answer (score 2):

Как было отмечено автором сообщения в комментариях, в буфере число находится не в чистом виде=> его необходимо отделить от текста.

Если в буфере всегда может быть только 1 число, то можно воспользоваться регуляркой вида `\d+` и результат регулярного выражение преобразовать к `int`

Можно так же стандартными строковыми функциями воспользоваться, если известно, что число идет после ':'

Comment: Не сработает, если в тексте идёт, скажем, 100 цифр подряд.

Comment: @VladD, Ну в любом случае, зависит от того, что автор ожидает в буфере. Основная идея- это привести строку в буфере к нормальному виду, что бы потом скастовать.

Comment: Ну это да. Я собственно чтобы автор вопроса понимал сложность задачи.